# Using flow to create case record by guest user can not be fired omni-channel

Tags: visual-workflow, omnichannel, experience-cloud, guest-user

I set up a screen flow to create a case record on Experience Cloud site.
It allows to use by Guest User, they can create a case record, and set case owner as a Queue. It has to be fired omni-channel when case owner is set as Queue.

However, if Guest User creates case record as I mentioned above, omni-channel is not fired as expected.
When System Administrator uses a flow that can fire omni-channel.

Therefore, omni-channel routing is set up correctly for system administrator, but not for Guest User. Is there any additional setup to work correctly?

Comment: Is case record created by guest  user?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi Yes.